# Odoo No module named base_multi_image

Tags: python, odoo

i try start odoo with magento connector, but how i add extensions odoo crashed

```
   ERROR ? werkzeug: Error on request:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 177, in run_wsgi
        execute(self.server.app)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 165, in execute
        application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/server.py", line 246, in app
        return self.app(e, s)
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 184, in application
        return application_unproxied(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/openerp/service/wsgi_server.py", line 170, in application_unproxied
        result = handler(environ, start_response)
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1492, in __call__
        self.load_addons()
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1513, in load_addons
        m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 61, in load_module
        mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/addons/product-attribute/product_multi_image/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
        from .hooks import pre_init_hook
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/addons/product-attribute/product_multi_image/hooks.py", line 5, in <module>
        from openerp.addons.base_multi_image.hooks import pre_init_hook_for_submodules
      File "/home/germania/odoo/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 60, in load_module
        f, path, descr = imp.find_module(module_part, ad_paths)
    ImportError: No module named base_multi_image
```

Without magento connector odoo start correctly

Answer (score 1):

you need to make sure that your add-on directory includes the following repo:
https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/9.0/base_multi_image